# What causes the cart service failure in this Angular 13 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

I am working on an e-commerce app who's front-end is made in Angular 13.

I use a `CartService` service to add products to the cart (`app\services\cart.service.ts`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from '../models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

  subject = new Subject();
  product: Product | undefined;

  constructor() { }

  sendProductTocart(product: Product) {
    this.subject.next(product);
  }
}
```

In `app\components\product-item\product-item.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, InputDecorator, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';
import { CartService } from '../../services/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-item',
  templateUrl: './product-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-item.component.css']
})
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product!: Product;
  @Input() handleAddToCart!: (args: any) => void;

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { }

  addToCart(product: Product) {
    console.log(this.cartService.product);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In `app\components\add-to-cart\add-to-cart.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit, InputDecorator, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../../models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-to-cart',
  templateUrl: './add-to-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-to-cart.component.css']
})
export class AddToCartComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product!: Product;
  @Input() handleAddToCart!: (args: any) => void;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

In `app\components\add-to-cart\add-to-cart.component.html`:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success w-100" (click)="handleAddToCart(product)">Add</button>
```

#### The goal

The goal is to add products to the top-cart component (`app\components\top-cart\top-cart.component.ts`), **more exactly**, to the `cartItems` array:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '.app-top-cart',
  templateUrl: './top-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-cart.component.css']
})
export class TopCartComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItems: any = [
    
  ];

  constructor() { }

  totalPrice: number = 0;

  doTotalPrice() {
    let total = 0;
    this.cartItems.forEach((item: { price: number, quantity: number }) => {
      item.quantity = 1;
      total += item.price * item.quantity
    });
    this.totalPrice = total;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.doTotalPrice();
  }

}
```

#### Stackblitz

See Stackblitz demo **[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r1yymn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**.

#### The problem

For a reason I have not been able to find out, when I click the "Add to cart" button in the product list, I get this error in the Ghrome console:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined
```

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: I see that `product` is decorated with `@Input` but I could not find in which template was it set. Perhaps the problems is that you forgot to instantiate `product`.

Comment: One trick with error messages is to sometimes use a different browser. With firefox I have error `this.cartService is undefined`. Somehow injection is going wrong

Comment: `addToCart` is getting called in `AddToCartComponent` which doesn't know about `cartService`

Comment: It's not the best idea to pass a handler to a child. It's not an Angular's approach. Instead emit event from the child and handle it in the parent component. Or create a service which would handle such case

Comment: @Sergey What about the service? Can't _it_ do the "heavy loading"? How?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir call the service's method directly in the child

Comment: @Sergey Did that, but `console.log(this.cartService.product)` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir did you assign it first?

Comment: @Sergey See the code **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r1yymn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this, passing function down to child

```
  <div class="card-footerer p-1">
    <app-add-to-cart [handleAddToCart]="addToCart"></app-add-to-cart>
  </div>
```

But in your child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-to-cart',
  templateUrl: './add-to-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-to-cart.component.css']
})
export class AddToCartComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product!: Product;
  @Input() handleAddToCart!: (args: any) => void;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

the service `cartService` is not injected into this child component. `this` is not passed down but is referring now to `AddToCartComponent`. And `this.cartService` is not defined. So it's throwing error
`ERROR Error: this.cartService is undefined` (in firefox)

#### Alternative

Use an event emitter to pass the data up and handle event in parent.

```
export class AddToCartComponent {
  @Input() product!: Product;
  @Output() productAdded: EventEmitter<Product> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  handleAddToCart(product: Product) {
      this.productAdded.emit(product)
  }
}
```

```
 <app-add-to-cart (productAdded)="addToCart($event)"></app-add-to-cart>
```

Comment: I have a **cart service** in `app\services\cart.service.ts`. What do you mean by "the service cartService doesn't exist"?

Comment: As far as `AddToCartComponent` is concerned `cartService` doesn't exist. It's calling `this.cartService` (the passed function) but it doesn't have `cartService` declared in this component, nor should it.

Comment: the function is passed to the child but not the instance of `this` that is in `ProductItemComponent` that does know about `cartService`

Comment: The goal is to add products to the `cartItems` array of the `top-cart` component. I apologize if I had not made that clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the product:

now:

```
        <div class="card-footerer p-1">
                <app-add-to-cart [handleAddToCart]="addToCart"></app-add-to-cart>
        </div>
```

should be:

```
        <div class="card-footerer p-1">
                <app-add-to-cart [handleAddToCart]="addToCart"
                                 [product]="product"></app-add-to-cart>
        </div>
```